# imagebutton for different screen size

Tags: java, android

I have a problem with supporting screen size for ImageButton.
when adding ImageButton the image is much bigger than the screen size and half of it is outside the screen limit.
I tried by changing the size for every image, but in (4 inches screen size) the image appears smaller than other screens size  .

is there any way I can make from xml, not to add many differet size to dpi folder

Hopefully someone can help.
thanks a lot

main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
   android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
   android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
   android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
   android:background="@drawable/walla"
   tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<FrameLayout
   android:id="@+id/frameLayout1"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
   android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" >

   <ImageButton
     android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_marginBottom="154dp"
     android:background="@null"
     android:src="@drawable/hex_button_one" />

</FrameLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thats why different dpi folder was made so the image changes sizes everytime on different screens.. make sure that you put it on the rightfolder your image.

Comment: I did it, but the image appears rather smaller than other screens size or bigger not on the size

Comment: Use a android:scaleType="fitCenter" to have Android scale the images, andandroid:adjustViewBounds="true" to have them adjust their bounds due to scaling.